# Magento - Accessing a customer's wishlist

Tags: magento

I would like to be able to load a customer's wishlist and return the product id's of the products within the list

I am using:

```
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
```

The problem is that the arrays in the Item Collection are protected and I can't find any methods to extract the data.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're very close to your target.

```
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
    $arrProductIds = array();

    foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $arrProductIds[] = $product->getId();
    }
}
```

The array variable `$arrProductIds` will now contain the list of all Product IDs that have been wishlisted by that specific Customer.

Comment: You can also simply use $item->getProductId(); - no need to load the whole product.

Comment: From a re-usability standpoint, getting the entire product makes more sense though. Such as displaying the product name as well as the link, you'll need more than just an ID.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is correct. There may be customer is not loaded. here is code.

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();

foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
{
   // do things
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In any template, using magento 1.8, this works

```
Total: <?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getItemCount() ?>

// Items
$this->helper('wishlist')->getWishlist()->getItemCollection();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$wishList = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();

foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
{
    //do your thing e.g. echo $item->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with product all details like name, images etc...

```
<?php
 $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
 if($customer->getId())
{
     $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
     $wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
     foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
     {
           echo $item->getName()."</br>";
           echo $item->getId()."</br>";
           echo $item->getPrice()."</br>";
           echo $item->getQty()."</br>";  
           $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($item->getStoreId())->load($item->getProductId());
          if ($item->getId()) :
?>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113); ?>" width="113" height="113" />
<?php endif; } } ?>
```